# Why is Xcode centering the next line of my code without me asking it to?

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode and for the most part I don't have any problems with it, but today it's been jumping lines of my code as soon as I type the semicolon the entire line centers itself. Here is an example:

```
TF1 * func = new TF1("func","log(x)-cos(5*x),0,3);
func->SetNpx(1000);
TCanvas * funcCnv = new TCanvas("funcCnv","Function",500,500);
fun->Draw();
double lowLim=0.2;
                  double uppLim=2;
```

For all of the other lines I had to individually backspace, and this is very time consuming. I was looking around and I saw that when there are problems with indentation you can go to Xcode-> Preference->Indentation, but when I open the menu I don't see that option. 
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The second string in the first line is not closed. This confuses the editor in Xcode.

Comment: @macmoonshine that fixed it! An obvious mistake on my behalf, I suppose. Thank you.